# Cannot make C# View static for passing data from controller to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to pass a string from a Controller to a view and Im not quite sure what Im missing. I cannot make the action method in the controller static because the View then errors with

> an object reference is required for the non-static field.

How do I fix this? I would appreciate a detailed explanation, or links to your sources so I can learn.

My controller (LC) has:

```
...
public ActionResult Action()
{
    LC vm = new LC();
    vm.LicenseTable = DataPull(); //setting a variable in the controller
    return View("LicenseView", vm); //return a view named 'LicenseView'
}
...
```

my lcview.cshtml:

```
@using iw.Models //yes I screwed up and put a controller in the models folder
@model LC
<body>
    //<p>@LC.LicenseView</p> //calling the Model the the View name FAILS
    <p>@LC.Action()</p> //Fails because of error below
</body>
```

Error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static method LC.Action()

Comment: In your cshtml, use <p>@Model.Action()</p>

Comment: The "@model LC" declares the object type used as the model, but when you need to access the actual object you use the "model" keyword instead.

Comment: `<p>@Model.Action()</p>`

Comment: If your Controller is called LC, are you instantiating a new LC Controller in your Action method and making it a type of ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, in your cshtml, use

```
<p>@Model.Action()</p>
```

The "@model LC" declares the object type used as the model, but when you need to access the actual object you use the "model" keyword instead.

**EDIT**

Are you trying to display the LC.LicenseTable string in the HTML?
Use the following:

```
<p>@Model.LicenseTable</p>
```

Comment: When I try this I get: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Are you trying to display LC.LicenseTable in your html? I've updated my answer to show how to do this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call the action method named `Action` of your controller name `LC`.

You need to use `Html.Action` as it looks like you want to call the action and render view in the `p` element:

```
<p>@Html.Action("Action","LC")</p>
```

We specify the controller name and action name in this method and it will return the view which will be rendered as html.

Comment: when I try this I get an error that says: `requires receiver of type urlhelper`